# Perl if condition parameters

Tags: linux, perl, if-statement, hash

I have a log file which looks like below:

```
4680 p4exp/v68     PJIANG-015394 25:34:19 IDLE none
8869 unnamed p4-python       R integration semiconductor-project-trunktip-turbolinuxclient 01:33:52 IDLE none
8870 unnamed p4-python       R integration remote-trunktip-osxclient 01:33:52
```

There are many such entries in the same log file such that some contains IDLE none at the end while some does not. I would like to retain the ones having "R integration" and "IDLE none" in a hash and ignore the rest. I have tried the following code but not getting the desired results.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open (FH,'/root/log.txt');
my %stat;
my ($killid, $killid_details);
while ($line = <FH>) {
    if ($line =~ m/(\d+)/){
            $killid = $1;
    }
    if ($line =~ /R integration/ and $line =~ /IDLE none/){
            $killid_details = $line;
    }
    $stat{$killid} = {
            killid => $killid_details
    };
}
close (FH);
```

I am getting all the lines with R integration (for example I get 8869, 8870 lines) which should not be the case as 8870 should be ignored.

Please inform me if any mistake. I am still learning perl. Thank you.

Comment: Add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your program and see if that can clear up some of your errors.

Comment: What's the expected outcome of this?

Comment: You need to add `else { next; }` clauses to your `if` statements, so you skip to the next line when they don't match. I think you may also need to change your `$stat{$killid}` assignment, but it's hard to say since you don't say what the expected result is.

Comment: I have edited it. Sorry for the mistake. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a few changes in your program:

- Always put in `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. These will catch 90% of your errors. (Although not this time).
- When you open a file, you need to either use `or die` as in `open my $fh, "<", $file or die qq(blah, blah, blah);` or use `use autodie;` (which is now preferred). In your case, if the file didn't open, your program would have continued merrily along. You need to test whether or not the `open` statement worked.
- Note my `open` statement. I use a variable for the file handle. This is preferred because it's not global, and it's easier to pass into subroutines. Also note I use the three parameter `open`. This way, you don't run into trouble if your file name begins with some strange character.
- When you declare a variable, it's best to do it *in scope*. This way, variables go out of scope when you no longer need them. I moved where `$killid` and `$killid_details` to be declared inside the loop. That way, they no longer exist outside the loop.
- You need to be more careful with your regular expressions. What if the phrase `IDLE none` appears elsewhere in your line? You only want it if its on the end of the line.

Now, for the issues you had:

- You need to `chomp` lines when you read them. In Perl, the NL at the end of the line is read in. The `chomp` command removes it.
- Your logic was a bit strange. You set `$killid` if your line had a digit in it (I modified it to look only for digits at the beginning of the line). However, you simply went on your merry way even if `killid` was not set. In your version, because you declared `$killid` outside of the loop, it had a value in each loop. Here I go to the next statement if `$killid` isn't defined.
- You had a weird definition for your hash. You were defining a reference hash within a hash. No need for that. I made it a simple hash.

Here it is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $log_fh, '<', '/root/log.txt';

my %stat;
while (my $line = <$log_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    next if not $line =~ /^(\d+)\s+/;
    my $killid = $1;
    if ($line =~ /R\s+integration/ and $line =~ /IDLE\s+none$/){
        my $killid_details = $line;
        $stat{$killid} = $killid_details;
    }
}
close $log_fh;

say Dumper \%stat;
```

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation. Excellent step by step guide for starters like me. Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably what you want:

```
while (<FH>) {
    next unless /^(\d+).*R integration.*IDLE none/;
    $stat{$1} = $_;
}
```

The regexp should be anchored to the beginning of the line, so you don't match a number anywhere on the line. There's no need to do multiple regexp matches, assuming the order of `R integration` and `IDLE none` are always as in the example. You need to use `next` when there's no match, so you don't process non-matching lines.

And I suspect that you just want to set the value of the hash entry to the string, not a reference to another hash.